# Chosen Jquery Plugin - getting selected values

Tags: jquery, jquery-chosen

How can i get the selected values from the chosen Multi-select Box?

Comment: @Andrew it's a reasonable question - I too wondered if Chosen was properly modifying the underlying select box (turned out to be a DOM inspector not refreshing properly).

Comment: @nailer My issue is not with the reasonableness, it is with the effort put into the question. Which in this case is close to none. Go through the four points in my link and tell me if any of them were demonstrated here.

Comment: @Andrew Excellent point.

Comment: @arvind, I used your code and worked for me too for displaying multi-select. I added var1=$(this).val() to store but dont know how to submit var1 with form. Working on it.

Answer (score 70, accepted):

Like from any regular input/select/etc...:

```
$("form.my-form .chosen-select").val()
```

Comment: this is not the correct way.. because, if same page have multiple selectbox it will return fake value :)

Comment: This the correct answer.The result though is an array and my question is how am I going to extract the values from the array so I can put them in the db.I just need some hint on the PHP code needed here.

Answer (score 99):

```
$("#select-id").chosen().val()
```

Comment: This worked for me in comparison to the accepted answer which did not.

Comment: Shows me `TypeError: $(...).chosen.val is not a function`

Comment: @shankshera yes, I got it with the `val()`. this error showed up in the console that chosen is not a valid function. but my other chosen api's are working fine.

Comment: @Lucky your code actually lacks two sets of `()`. One after `chosen` and one after `val`. Try `$(...).chosen().val()`

Comment: This works for me, but I'd like to comment that chosen creates a div underneath the select. This is not what you are targetting with .chosen().

I mistakenly set my query selector as '#select-id_chosen', but the correct selector was '#select-id'. When selecting the wrong tag with jquery, and then using the .chosen() method, it returns this error: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined.

Answer (score 18):

This worked for me

```
$(".chzn-select").chosen({

     disable_search_threshold: 10

}).change(function(event){

     if(event.target == this){
        alert($(this).val());
     }

});
```

Answer (score 13):

```
$("#select-id").chosen().val()
```

this is the right answer, I tried, and the value passed is the values separated by ","

Comment: This doesnt work for me - i land up getting 2 copies of the variable (when i have 2 options selected in the `chosen`), so something like this is obtained: `var[] = 111;  var[]=3348;`

Answer (score 9):

If anyone wants to get only the selected value on click to an option, he can do the follow:

```
$('.chosen-select').on('change', function(evt, params) {
    var selectedValue = params.selected;
    console.log(selectedValue);
});
```

Comment: You can directly reference the original select element(s) in the selector as well, too, rather than using chosen's applied `.chosen-select` class.

Answer (score 7):

As of 2016, you can do this more simply than in any of the answers already given:

```
$('#myChosenBox').val();
```

where "myChosenBox" is the id of the original select input.  Or, in the change event:

```
$('#myChosenBox').on('change', function(e, params) {
    alert(e.target.value); // OR
    alert(this.value); // OR
    alert(params.selected); // also in Panagiotis Kousaris' answer
}
```

In [the Chosen doc](https://harvesthq.github.io/chosen/options.html), in the section near the bottom of the page on triggering events, it says "Chosen triggers a number of standard and custom events on the original select field."  One of those standard events is the change event, so you can use it in the same way as you would with a standard select input.  You don't have to mess around with using Chosen's applied classes as selectors if you don't want to.  (For the `change` event, that is.  Other events are often a different matter.)

Answer (score 3):

if you want to get text of a selected option
(chosen get display selected value)

```
 $("#select-id").chosen().find("option:selected" ).text();
```

Comment: This or `$("#select-id").chosen().find("option:selected" ).attr('somArbitraryAttributeNameFromOptionElement')`

Answer (score 2):

This solution worked for me

```
var ar = [];
$('#id option:selected').each(function(index,valor){
    ar.push(valor.value);
});
console.log(ar);
```

be sure to have your `<option>` tags with they correspondant `value` attribute.
Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

I believe the problem occurs when targeting by ID, because Chosen will copy the ID from the original `select` onto it's newly created `div`, leaving you with 2 elements of the same (now not-unique) ID on the current page.

When targeting Chosen by ID, use a selector specific to the `select`:

```
$( 'select#yourID' ).on( 'change', function() {
    console.log( $( this ).val() );
} );
```

...instead of...

```
$( '#yourID' ).on( 'change', function() {
    console.log( $( this ).val() );
} );
```

This works because Chosen mirrors its selected items back to the original (now hidden) `select` element, even in multi-mode.

(It also continues to work with or without Chosen, say... if you decide to go a different direction in your application.)