# how to get the selected value of a cloned chosen select dropdown

Tags: clone, jquery-chosen

I am using jquery chosen on a select box. Then I am cloning this to display same select box in other div. Here I am just cloning the select box and not the entire div because if i clone whole div it will clone the html added by chosen(). Now I want to get the selected option in last select box which I have cloned.

```
<select class="chosen-select" id="critaria-1" data-placeholder="Choose ...">
<option value="text">Text</option>
                        <option value="Department">Department</option>
                        <option value="Country">Country</option>
                        <option value="State">State</option>
                        <option value="Industry">Industry</option>
                        <option value="Sub-Industry">Sub-Industry</option>
                        <option value="Revenue">Revenue</option>
                        <option value="Title">Title</option>
                        <option value="Employees">Number of employees</option>
                        <option value="News">News</option>
                        <option value="Intrests">Intrests</option>
                        <option value="Interaction">Social Interaction</option>
                    </select>
```

JS code :

```
var clone_search = $('.chosen-select').last().clone(); 
        clone_search.prop('id','critaria-' + id); // add a new id 
        clone_search.find('option:selected').remove(); // remove the last selected
```

Actually I dont want to repeat the selected option from parent in the cloned select box

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10521315/chosen-jquery-plugin-getting-selected-values   $("#select-id").chosen().val()

Answer (score 0):

```
$("#select-id").chosen().val()
```